# Assertion Failure when trying to Swap two Elements in a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

std::vector<std::string> readIn(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::vector<std::string> strVec;
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    std::string line;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> line;
        strVec.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
    return strVec;
}
void sortVector(std::vector<std::string>& strVec)
{
    size_t size = strVec.size();
    for (size_t j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (size_t k = i; strVec[k][j] > strVec[k + 1][j]; k++)
                strVec[k].swap(strVec[k+1]); //CRASHES HERE
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "input.txt";
    std::vector<std::string> strVec = readIn(fileName);
    size_t size = strVec.size();
    std::cout << "Words in file:" << std::endl
        << "before sorting:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << strVec[i] << " ";
    sortVector(strVec);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "after sorting:" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << strVec[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having with this is sorting the strings my vector. More specifically, the program isn't fond of `strVec[k].swap(strVec[k+1]);` in my `sortVector()` function. The debugger also says that my `vector` is being filled correctly:

[image]

So `readIn()` doesn't *appear* to be the problem (as the program breaks while in `sortVector()`), but I posted it anyways.

Perhaps I shouldn't be giving up so quickly, but I've Googled this and read everything I can about vectors (and strings in vectors), and I'm still stumped. Any feedback you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's the contents of my `input.txt` file:

```
This is a test input file for CS250's CS161 programming pre-requisite assignment

This file contains a number of words and lines, but nothing terribly important.
```

Comment: Why not use `std:sort()`?

Comment: @HappyCoder That's actually really helpful, although I would like to know why I'm running into this error.

Comment: `for (size_t j = 4; j >= 0; j--)` this will never terminate

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that you don't have any checks to make sure that you don't access the vector out of bounds.

Change

```
for (size_t k = i; strVec[k][j] > strVec[k + 1][j]; k++)
    strVec[k].swap(strVec[k+1]);
```

to

```
for (size_t k = i; k < size-1 && strVec[k][j] > strVec[k + 1][j]; k++)
    strVec[k].swap(strVec[k+1]);
```

Since you are accessing `strVec[k+1]`, `k` must be less than `size-1`.

That will lead to problems if `size` is `0`. You can get around that problem by using `int` for `size` and `k` instead of `size_t`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue. :/

Comment: @Larrimus, can you post the minimal input for which you see the problem?

Comment: Here's a dropbox link to my input file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/487duxt1c1kybbh/input.txt?dl=0

Comment: Is the file too large to add its contents to your post? If not please add its contents to the post. If it is not, try to create a minimal version of the file that still creates the problem. We don't like external links to important content in questions and answers if it contains data.